# Apple Launcher visible behind part of app

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, view

Here's what our search bar is supposed to look like:

[image]

And here's what is sometimes happening:

[image]

Notice how the iOS launcher is visible behind the search bar. WTF, right? This shouldn't even be possible, but we've seen it 2-3 times, each time without a clear set of steps to reproduce.

So I'm interested in answers to any of these questions, from least-useful to most:

- Have you seen this before? (Details, please.)
- What could be causing this?
- Do you know how to solve this?

Comment: I would also like to know why this is, I remember coming across it once.

Comment: Is one of your views transparent?

Comment: If you want a useful answer, you're probably going to have to tell us more about how those views are set up, maybe even show some code.

Comment: You could try grabbing the layer and beating on it with setNeedsDisplay, display, etc. and see if any of that helps.

Comment: @Caleb, I wouldn't know where to begin showing code, given that the full view hierarchy gets created with the help of various view controllers, .xibs, and the app delegate. It works 99% of the time, so it seems unlikely that there's any obvious problems with the setup.

Comment: is your iPhone jailbroken? I didnt have seen such a behaviour...

Comment: @onnoweb That was my first thought, but then I did a test where I built the app with no rootViewController added to the main window. All I got was a black screen, which means that any subviews with transparency would just show up black as well...as expected.

Answer (score 2):

That's the Springboard.app's last buffered drawing- the application is not visually open behind your application. This means your buffer has gone crazy because of some drawing code that was applied incorrectly. On Mac OS X, this results in garbled windows.

Comment: Any idea what could be causing this to happen so unpredictably, or what type of drawing code mistake could be involved?

Comment: Would you mind posting your drawing code for me to examine? Just the portion which has issues.

Comment: Sorry, I wouldn't know where to begin. There's no custom drawing here that I know of...just layering of views using -addSubview:

Comment: Thanks for offering to keep plugging at this, @Galaxas0. I've had to put it to bed as we've got bigger fires in the pan, and it's been so rare. In the end, we threw in a spare black view behind the search bar and we're hoping that'll suffice as a workaround. I don't want to mislead folks into thinking we've got a working solution here by checking off your answer, but I did up-vote it.

Comment: Oh, ok, that's fine with me :] As long as your issue is fixed :]